# strtotime returns different results on different PHP versions

Tags: php, strtotime

I came across a weird problem with `strtotime` function returning different (and I think incorrect) results.

This is my test code and results:

```
$fromTime = strtotime('2013-10-22');
$toTime = strtotime('2013-10-28');
$days = ($toTime - $fromTime) / (3600 * 24);

var_dump($days, $fromTime, $toTime);

// PHP 5.2.5 on codepad.org - correct
// int(6)
// int(1382400000)
// int(1382918400)

// PHP 5.3.15, PHP 5.4.6 - incorrect I guess
// float(6.0416666666667)
// int(1382392800)
// int(1382914800)
```

You can see it live on http://codepad.org/gdTqFLqG.
Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried to replicate the same problem using PHP's `DateTime` class?

Comment: +1 to @N.B.'s suggestion to use the DateTime class instead -- You shouldn't really be using `strtotime()` for this kind of thing today.

Comment: I'm already using `DateTime` instead of `strtotime`. Format 'Y' works as expected, I was just curious why is this happening.

Comment: Sorry, `format('U')` of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @N.B.'s suggestion to use the DateTime class instead -- You shouldn't really be using `strtotime()` for this kind of thing today.

However, as for why it's happening, look at the dates you're comparing.... what often happens between those dates? Yep, that's right -- daylight savings.

So my guess is that it's got nothing to do with the PHP version, and more to do with the timezone setup on the different platforms you're testing. One is set to use the UCT and the other is set to use a local timezone that has DST.

Comment: I'm OK with DateTime class, I was just curious why `strtotime` doesn't return correct value. I'm sure it's not a timezone problem because it makes this error only with some specific dates.

Comment: @Martin: The timestamp given by your `strtotime()` calls will be for local midnight on the given date. On a server with a DST timezone, midnight will be offset by an hour for half the year. If your two dates are on different sides of the DST clock changes, this means that your date diff will give either *"X days and 1 hour"* or *"X-1 days and 23 hours"*. Shown as a float, this will be *6.041666* or *5.958333*. This is why you should always ensure that your server is using UCT as its base timezone for all internal processing, converting to/from local time only for input/output.

Answer (score 0):

You should use date_default_timezone_set(), cause in second test you got correct time with some UTC+- correction.